# C# Run Function when User Exits

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to call a function in C# when the user exists the application?

I'm using Visual C# 2008 Express edition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a windows forms applications, isn't it? You can use this event:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ApplicationExit += ...
```

Comment: Working from memory, there is a similar concept in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it so this may be a shot in the dark, but couldn't one override the default exit method and do something like protected override exit {myMethod(); base(e);}
Though I'm assuming delegation does essentially the same thing in this case